# Mule inbound endpoint is not picking file

Tags: mule, endpoint, inbound

```
<flow name="receive-files-from-client">
        <file:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="ibFileConnector"
                               path="/client-data/accounts/client/ToTest">
            <file:filename-wildcard-filter pattern="ABC_123*.txt, XYZ_987*.txt" />

            <object-to-byte-array-transformer />   <!-- need to convert from an input stream to a byte array to avoid having the wire-tap close it -->

            <wire-tap>
                <file:outbound-endpoint path="${workingDdir}/Dir1/archive/inbound/#[function:datestamp-yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss.SSS]" />
            </wire-tap>
        </file:inbound-endpoint>

....
...
</flow>
```

I have Configured everything properly, But Mule is not picking the file from that inbound path location.

Comment: Can you see in the logs if the file is not being picked up or if it is filtered out?

Comment: After some changes Mule is trying to access file But error is :        ERROR... [[Application-1.0-SNAPSHOT].inboundFileConnector.receiver.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy: 
*********
Message               : File "CYC53_855.001234txt" does not exist or cannot be read
Code                  : MULE_ERROR-6
-----------------------------

Answer (score 0):

Use the following modified flow.  You are using a file outbound inside a file inbound.

```
<flow name="receive-files-from-client">
        <file:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="inboundFileConnector"
                               path="/client-ftpdata/ftpaccounts/client/To_CC-Test">
            <file:filename-wildcard-filter pattern="CYC53_810*.txt,CYC53_855*.txt,CYC53_856*.txt,CYC53_997*.txt" />

            <object-to-byte-array-transformer />   <!-- need to convert from an input stream to a byte array to avoid having the wire-tap close it -->

            <wire-tap>
                <file:outbound-endpoint path="${global.workdir}/suppliers/S000590/archive/inbound/#[function:datestamp-yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss.SSS]" />
            </wire-tap>
        </file:inbound-endpoint>
            <wire-tap>
                <file:outbound-endpoint path="${global.workdir}/suppliers/S000590/archive/inbound/#[function:datestamp-yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss.SSS]" />
            </wire-tap>


....
...
</flow>
```

Try to execute your flow without filter and see if the flow is picking the files. If so modify your filter regular expression.

Hope this helps.